# RESTful Login Failure: Return 401 or Custom Response

Tags: http, rest, authentication, http-response-codes

This is a conceptual question.

I have a client (mobile) application which needs to support a login action against a RESTful web service.  Because the web service is RESTful, this amounts to the client accepting a username/password from the user, verifying that username/password with the service, and then just remembering to send that username/password with all subsequent requests.

All other responses in this web service are provided in a JSON format.

The question is, when I query the web service simply to find out whether a given username/password are valid, should the web service always respond with JSON data telling me its successful or unsuccessful, or should it return HTTP 200 on good credentials and HTTP 401 on bad credentials.

The reason I ask is that some other RESTful services use 401 for bad credentials even when you're just asking if the credentials are valid.  However, my understanding of 401 responses are that they represent a resource that you are not supposed to have access to without valid credentials.  But the login resource SHOULD be accessible to anyone because the entire purpose of the login resource is to tell you if your credentials are valid.

Put another way, it seems to me that a request like:

```
myservice.com/this/is/a/user/action
```

should return 401 if bad credentials are provided.  But a request like:

```
myservice.com/are/these/credentials/valid
```

should never return 401 because that particular URL (request) is authorized with or without valid credentials.

I'd like to hear some justified opinions one way or the other on this.  What is the standard way of handling this, and is the standard way of handling this logically appropriate?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

First off. 401 is the proper response code to send when a failed login has happened.

> **401 Unauthorized**
> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.

Your confusion about, `myservice.com/are/these/credentials/valid` sending back 401 when you just do a check, I think is based on the fact that doing boolean requests in REST often is wrong by the RESTful constraints. Every request should return a resource. Doing boolean questions in a RESTful service is a slippery sloop down to RPC.

Now I don't know how the services that you looked on are behaving. But a good way of solving this is to have something like an Account object, that you try to GET. If your credentials are correct, you will get the Account object, if you don't want to waste bandwidth just to do a "check" you can do a HEAD on the same resource.

An Account Object is also a nice place to store all those pesky boolean values that otherwise would be tricky to create individual resources for.

Comment: Your point about returning resources seems valid and maybe that's the right move here.  As for stating that 401 is the proper response, I'd appreciate some explanation there.  I've read the HTTP spec, as you have included here, but that to me does not read as a direct and obvious confirmation of your assertion.  Namely, authentication is NOT required to ask about the validity of credentials - yet what you included says "specifically for use when authentication is required."

Comment: Your way of looking at it is correct. You don't need to be authenticated to be able to ask for your Account object. But you need to successfully authenticate to be able to receive the resource, and thats where `authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided` applies, since you don't ask for the validity of credentials, but for a specific resource based on the credentials you supply.

Comment: Right, I guess I stated my comment ambiguously.  IF an account resource is returned, I'm on your same page - I agree with your stance.  When I asked again about the 401 I meant only with regard to the case where I am asking for validity.  I understand this is "wrong" from a REST approach, but I'd just like to reach a conclusion for the sake of this question.  So if I do the wrong thing and ask for validity as a boolean return, would it be inappropriate to return a 401 given that authentication is not actually required for that request/query?

Comment: I understand why you want to do a "check-call" and for that, I would still promote 401 as the appropriate response code for a failed authentication, even if the call does not require authentication to to be callable. A 204 No Content might also be suitable, but feels a bit ambiguously.

Comment: I don't see how this can be correct, unless you are using Basic or Digest authentication.  Per the quoted part of the spec: "The response must include a WWW-Authenticate" -- and if you refer to section 14.47: "The HTTP access authentication process is described in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication".  This implies to me that 401 is not appropriate if you are using typical email/password validation.

Comment: In this scenario, client code is able to invoke the server API and as a result, the server API is able to perform some operation at the server side. So, obviously no problem of accessing the API. So 401 is not appropriate. As the result of the operation, the API found that the given credentials does not match with valid combinations (No Record Found). Hence the API decided to say "authentication failed". Hence Status code 204 is appropriate.

Comment: This is not the right answer. I don't know why it's accepted. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html The right response is 400.

Comment: I think this may be wrong, I have been implementing clients both web and mobile and I intercept 401 to redirect to login screen. But when someone is already on the login screen and submits wrong credentials, the response also has 401 and will try to redirect again. There should be a different status code for failed attempt to get authenticated when trying explicitly. Maybe a bad request or even server error?

Comment: @Ilko according to the link you provided it clearly states that "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.". Therefore 400 should be used when the client has sent something that the server perceive as erroneous, not for a login credential being incorrect.

Comment: @JaphethOngeri-inkalimeva how your client deals with non explicit redirects is up to your client. A 401 only states that there was issues with the provided credentials or that they are missing. A 30X code can communicate an appropriate redirect or a link header can be provided to tell your client if and where to redirect if the server knows what it wants the client to do.

Comment: @maris Using a 204 is insanely wrong, unless you think a failed login attempt qualifies as "[request has succeeded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204#:~:text=request%20has%20succeeded)" and nothing is returned in the response.

Answer (score 46):

401 should be sent only when the request needs authorization header field and authorization fails. Since the Login API doesn't require authorization, hence 401 is the wrong error code in my opinion

As per the standard here https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

*10.4.2 401 Unauthorized

**The request requires user authentication.** The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication" [43].*

Comment: I agree with you on this, but what is the alternative response status to send? I have been implementing clients both web and mobile and I intercept 401 to redirect to login screen. But when someone is already on the login screen and submits wrong credentials, the response also has 401 and will try to redirect again... what would you do?

Comment: This seems correct. The login request does not require authorization by definition. So how can it fail authorization! That makes no sense. I think a 403 or 404 is the right response as we cannot reach a resource with the inputs.

Comment: I totally agree with this and that's how I've done my API's. I know we "think" about this as the Authentication endpoint. If we think of this as another resource, (even if the "resource" is a bool) a `404 Not Found` is proper because the payload provided did not find a resource who's (let's say) username and password match any record. Therefore, a `404 Not Found` is correct in my opinion.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs 404 implies that the login/auth endpoint doesn't exist. Use 400 or 422.

Answer (score 6):

It is **logical** to use `401` http status code when access to a resource is denied because the request **lacks or has incorrect credentials**. And when **correct** credentials are provided, the request should complete successfully granting access to the protected resource.
Applicable for your case: `myservice.com/this/is/a/user/action`.

#### Maybe we should be clear about this credentials

In most secure applications, *credentials are needed to access protected resource(s)*. These credentials can be sent along every request via HTTP header. Specifically the *`Authorization` Header*.
Therefore the Authorization header contains **credentials to allow a user to access protected resource(s)**.

> Remember that a user who was verified successfully as an authorized user(successful login), is the one given this *priviledged **credentials*** to allow for access on protected resources on the server.

From the server point of view, a HTTP request targeting a protected resource yet it is **lacking** *credentials*  or containing **invalid** *credentials* may cause to **validly send back `401` response code**.

Therefore the Login API should not send a `401` response code because of a failed login attempt. *It is misleading*. Reasoning out that you are requesting to the server application via the Login API to grant you with *credentials* required to access resources that are protected. By itself, the Login API is **not** a protected resource.

#### So what is the correct response status?

Well I will opine towards sending back a `400` response code because a failed login attempt is a client error who is at fault for not providing the correct *username or password*.

According to [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-400-bad-request) standards about 400 code:

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)

Again I will reiterate that failed login is a *client error* due to providing details that are incorrect. Sending back a 400 doesn't have to mean that the request syntax is malformed. But a malformed syntax is one of the reasons.

Sending a 401 would really be misleading as the user doesn't need to provide authentication information to access the login API.

Comment: 422 is another possibility, and is becoming more popular for validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

If the 401 response code is misleading for user authentication, the API can send HTTP status code 200 OK for both successful and failed authentication, but set a custom header on the authentication successful response and omit that header on failed logins.

The client can check if the header exists or not and decide the action.

Example: SpringBoot API Response

The call to OK when login is successful sets the header "gotyouin" with a value (anything). Call to failed does not add the header and client can treat this as a failed login attempt.

```
public class LoginResponseEntityHelper {
   public static ResponseEntity<?> ok(String token) {
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).header("gotyouin", token).body(null);
    }

    public static ResponseEntity<?> failed() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
    }}
```

Comment: 200 would work with optional headers or payload. There are other possibilities. 404 is also possible here as the resource could not be reached with the paramaters.

Comment: @SmileBot 404 implies that the login/auth endpoint doesn't exist. Use 400 or 422.

Answer (score 0):

I think a valid response for a login failure is 409 (conflict), as it implies there is something wrong **in the content being post**.

A 401 implies the requested resource needs authorization. A login doesn't.

A 403 or 404 implies there is something wrong with the request itself, though using one of these could be valid too.