# How to implement login in an Android application

Tags: android, authentication, httpresponse

I'm a beginner and I just can't find a solution that would work.

What I want to do:
User types in username and password, and the application logs in to a website. If the login is unsuccessful it returns false and a proper message, otherwise it returns true and proceeds to the next activity (gets another site, parses html, and displays content).

Where I'm stuck at: How to detect a successful login?

Here's my code

Relevant code from **LoginActivity**:

```
    Authentication auth = new Authentication();                     
    boolean loginSuccess = auth.authenticateUser(username, pass);

    if (!loginSuccess) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Invalid username or password.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                 
    }

    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Method from **Authentication** class:

```
public boolean authenticateUser(String username, String pass) {

boolean loginSuccess = false;       
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();        
String result = "";

try {           
    result = httpRequest.getResult(username, pass);
    Log.d("RESULT", result);            

        // Checking if it was a successful login    
    if (**SOMETHING**) loginSuccess = true;         
    } catch (ParseException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           

return loginSuccess;                
}
```

Since I get 200 (OK) status, I think the code for POST works ok, so I won't put the whole **HttpRequest** class here, just the most important methods:

```
public String getResult(String username, String pass) throws ParseException, IOException {
    String result = "";
    response = postData(username, pass);
    entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());                    
    }   

    return result;
}       

public HttpResponse postData(String username, String password) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpPost httpPost = getHttpPost(username, password);            
    HttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
    return httpClient.execute(httpPost);                
}

private HttpPost getHttpPost(String username, String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String url = "https://www.sitename.com/login.aspx";
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);      

    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUsername", username));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPassword", password));                
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

    return httpPost;        
}
```

So, what I'm missing is part of the code from Authentication class, where I need to see if it was a successful login. I don't know what to do with **result** variable that I got (or **response**, or **entity**).

Answer (score 0):

I think 200 (OK) status is sufficient to say that the login is successful. Otherwise, you should get 401 denied status code. Please see this question [RESTful Login Failure: Return 401 or Custom Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714485/restful-login-failure-return-401-or-custom-response).
You might modify the `getResult` to return Boolean and change your `getResult` to return **true** if the status is ok.

Comment: The thing is I checked the status both for invalid and valid login data, and it returned the same 200 code (I will recheck, but I'm pretty sure I didn't make some mistake). Also, I tried typing correct username and pass and then fetching the next web site, but all I got was the same login page (though that might have something to do with cookies?)

Comment: Yes I checked, 200 status is not enough, since I get it for invalid username and password. Any other suggestions? I have no idea. I tried reading response content, but all I get is some html and css, with nothing that would indicate login status.