# Django Rest Framework JWT 400 Bad Request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

By default when credentials are wrong, DRF-JWT return a response with 400 status. 
Why is it like that? 
When users don't provide correct login information, bad request log gets written in the browser's console. 
So I handle the error at the front but still it is not nice to have a console error message. 
So how can I override the JWT to not raise a 400, instead return success, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of bad login credentials, your server should return HTTP 401 or 400 error. More about that:

- [RESTful Login Failure: Return 401 or Custom Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714485/restful-login-failure-return-401-or-custom-response)
- [Issue in DRF-JWT repo: 400 or 401](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/107)

4XX stands for client-side errors. Bad credentials is the example of that case. There is nothing wrong with console error message resulted from bad request.