# My AJAX query isnt validating properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

New to web design here. I have a login form that validates and works perfectly in php but when I try and validate using ajax it doesn't work. When i run the page it says it is a success no matter the input into the form. I have tried for days trying to get it to validate in many different methods. If there is a better way please let me know!

php here and is on same page as login form

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo json_encode('true');
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;


    } else {
        echo json_encode('false');
        $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
    }
}


?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login_submit').click(function() {
      var form = $('#login_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "header.php",
        data: form,
        success:function (response){
                
                alert('Hi');
        
        },
        error: function(response){
                
                alert('Nope');
            
        }
          
        
   });
 });
});
```

```html
<form id="login_form" form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="loginform">
                
                <label class="login_form_labels"> Email:</label>
                
                <input type="email" id="email" class="login_input" name="email"><br><br>
                
                <label class="login_form_labels"> Password:</label>
                
                <input type="password" id="password" class="login_input" name="password"><br>
                
                <div id="stay_log">
                    Stay logged in.
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" value=1 id="checkbox_1">
                    
                </div>
                
                
                <input class="login_form_btn" name="login" value="Submit" type="Submit" id="login_submit">
                
                <button class="login_form_btn" type="button">Forget your Password?</button>

            </form>
```

Please help!

Comment: it can't say success  only  Hi or Nope and moust of the time will say Hi

Comment: are you getting the posted data in the php script??

Comment: you need to check the response within `success`

Comment: yes the php script gets the data, it logs in perfectly.

Comment: post the `response` on console or check using breakpoints on browser what are you getting in `response`

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: what is coming in response?

Comment: do you mean the alert response>

Comment: No I mean check `response` from `function(response)` what is coming from in it?

Answer (score 0):

First use alert(response) to find out the response you are getting. It should be true or false.

success:function (response){

```
            if(response === "true") 
           {
               alert("hi");
           }
           else
           {
             alert("nope");
           }
    },
```

Comment: Hi there i am getting nope as a response. why would that be?

Comment: Try adding `echo json_encode('true');` after you have added values in session

Comment: that didnt help :( ugh its probably really easy im just very new

Comment: @Mike, what are you getting after using alert(response) inside  success:function(response)

Comment: Should be `response === "true"`

Answer (score 0):

set **`dataType`** as **`Json`** in your **`ajax`** as like given below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "header.php",
    dataType: json,
    data: form,
    success:function (response){
            alert('Hi');
    },
    error: function(response){
            alert('Nope');
    }
});
```

Try this...

Comment: seems to not work, still says nope when form validates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to require pure JSON response from server side and handle it in your ajax success method.

**In your PHP code.**

```
$response=array();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email. "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo json_encode('true');
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;


        $response['type']="success";
        $response['message']="Login done successfully";


    } else {
        $response['type']="error";
        $response['message']="Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
    }
}
else
{
    $response['type']="error";
    $response['message']="invalid post request";
}

ob_clean();
echo json_encode($response);
die();
```

In above way from server you can response in only json format.

**In you ajax call javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login_submit').click(function() {
      var form = $('#login_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $('#login_form').attr("action"),
        data: form,
        dataType:'json'
        success:function (response){
                if(response.type=="success")
                {
                    alert(response.message);
                    // write code for handle your success login;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(response.message);
                    // write code for handle your failure login;

                }

        },
        error: function(response){

                alert('Nope');

        }


   });
 });
});
```

You have to handle JSON response from server side in your ajax success response

Comment: {"type":"error","message":"invalid post request"} this is all i get from doing that.

Comment: Your form is not sending data to your ajax request

Comment: I have modified answer for change ajax request url. please check it.

Comment: also  changed for check $_POST data in php script

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery/AJAX, the HTTP response code termines whether it is a success or not. So if the login failed, you should set a header in PHP indicating this failure.

```
if (.. login has failed .. ) {
  // HTTP 401 = 'Unauthorized'.
  http_response_code(401);  
}
```

By doing this, you won't even have to process the resulting JSON, only maybe to get additional info. But the basic result will tell you enough: if the `success` callback was called, logging in was successful. If `error` was called, it was not successful for whatever reason.

This sets out your basic flow, and after that you could parse the result message to see any details of what's going on (internal server error, user unknown, password doesn't match, etc).

See [List of HTTP response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error), for a list of alternatives and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714485/restful-login-failure-return-401-or-custom-response) for an argumentation about using 401.